# How to bring back removed spaces

Tags: c#, string, winforms, char, spaces

I have a string which has multiple spaces between the words and I want to remove these spaces and then bring them back .. The problem was in bringing the spaces back after deleting them I tried to code my idea but it runs without any output and some times it gives me an exception of "Index was outside of array bounds" .. any help

```
string pt = "My name is Code"
int ptLenght = pt.Length;
char[] buffer1 = pt.ToCharArray();
spaceHolder = new int[pt.Length];
for (int m = 0; m < pt.Length; m++)
{
    if (buffer1[m] == ' ')
    {
        hold = m;
        spaceHolder[m] = hold;
    }
}
char[] buffer = pt.Replace(" ", string.Empty).ToCharArray(); 
int stringRemovedSpaces = pt.Length;
char[] buffer = pt.ToCharArray(); // source
char[] buffer2 = new char[ptLenght]; // destination
for (int i = 0; i < pt.Length; i++)
{
    buffer2[i] = buffer[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < buffer2.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == spaceHolder[i])
    {
        for (int m = stringRemovedSpaces; m <= i; m--)
        {
            buffer2[m-1] = buffer2[m];
        }
        buffer2[i] = ' ';
    }
}
return new string(buffer2);
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you want exactly.  Why not make a new variable to hold the "spaceless" string and then reference your original variable when you want the spaces back?

Comment: Did your code remove *all* spaces perhaps? It's a lot easier and faster to *replace* multiple spaces with a single one using a regular expression: `Regex.Replace("A       B            C",@"\s+"," ")` will return `A B C`

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger (although you should really be doing what @maccettura says, you should still be able to diagnose yr code)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to replace multiple spaces with a single one. The fastest and easiest way to do this is with a simple regular expression that replaces multiple whitespaces with a single space, eg:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace("A     B      C",@"\s+"," ")
```

or

```
var newString = Regex.Replace("A     B      C",@"[ ]+"," ")
```

The reason this is fastest than other methods like repeated string replacements is that a regular expression does *not* generate temporary strings. Internatlly it generates a list of indexes to matching items. A string is generated only when the code asks for a string value, like a match or replacement.

A regular expression object is thread-safe as well. You can create it once, store it in a static field and reuse it :

```
static Regex _spacer = new Regex(@"\s+");


public void MyMethod(string someInput)
{
    ...
    var newString=_spacer.Replace(someInput, " ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the spaces in a string is really just as simple as calling the Replace function on a string. Please note that when you call Replace on a string, it does not modify the original string, it creates and returns a new string. I only bring this up because you set two different integer variables to `pt.Length`, and at no point is the string `pt` actually modified. Also, I would imagine you are getting the  "Index was outside of array bounds" from the nested for loop. You have the loop set up in a way that `m` will decrement forever. However, once `m` equals zero, you will be trying to access an index of -1 from `buffer2`, which is a no no. If you want to delete the spaces while retaining an original copy of the string you could simplify your code to this:

```
string pt = "My name is Code";
string newpt = pt.Replace(" ", string.empty);
```

pt is a string with spaces, newpt is a new string with spaces removed. However, if you want to replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single space, I would recommend  following the answer Panagiotis Kanavos gave.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the advice of @maccettura and I did it like this and it worked as I wished :)

```
 string orignalString = "";
 orignalString = pt;
 char[] buffer = pt.ToCharArray();
 orignalString = new string(buffer);
 return orignalString.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
 // Here I got the string without spaces , now I have the same string with and without spaces
```